# in vim, how to get rid of irritating "E141: No file name for buffer nn"

Tags: vim

This happens when I open an anonymous scratch file, and then do a `:wa`

even if I close the buffer.

Comment: Learn more about vim scratch files with command `:help special-buffers`.  Your E141 error happens because your buffer doesn't have a filename, set one with `:help buftype` and force a normal buffer with `:set buftype=` Then you can inflict a filename with: `:w foo.txt`  You can instruct vim to make your normal buffer back into a scratchfile with `:file scratch`.  See also what are vim scratch buffers: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11310/what-is-a-scratch-window

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your own answer is just curing the symptoms, not tackling the root cause.

It's better to properly indicate to Vim that your "scratch buffer" (which I guess is just by convention for you) is not meant to be persisted. That's what the `'buftype'` option is for. Open a scratch buffer with this (or create a corresponding mapping or command):

```
:new +setl\ buftype=nofile
```

Answer (score 1):

so you either need to save the buffer (and give it a name)

or since it's a scratch file, if you're done with it you need to force vim to delete it properly:

```
:b nn " where nn = the errant buffer
:bd! " kill the scratch file
```

use `:h bd` for more info

Comment: Nice tip, but why do you answer your own question immediately? No chance for others to find an answer :-)

Comment: mliebelt - you can give me a better answer if you want :-) @romainl - i googled this problem and couldn't find an answer, not even on SO (where 60%+ of my answers come from) - try yourself - if the SO curators provide an option for answer your own question is this just some kind of test? I happened to have an anwser, so I supplied it. I think Ingo's answer is better, and others can now agree, or not